# How to wrap command line script to a ./sh file

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have some script that needs to be executed on a remote instance in sequence.

1. `cd /srv/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin`
2. `sudo -s`
3. `source /etc/profile`
4. `./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown`

How can I make into a .sh file so I can ssh into the remote EC2 instance and run something like 
`ssh -i my-private-key ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xxx  '/scripts/backup.sh'`

Also, where should I put the ./sh file? When I log in myself, I run the command from the root folder. Now I need to let Jenkins to remote ssh into that instance and run the shell scripts like I did.

How do I do that? Thanks. I don't have knowledge about what .sh file is and how to run it, not to mention how to use Jenkins ssh into my EC2 instance and run those commands for me.

Comment: The big problem here is that the rest of your script won't run until `sudo -s` exits.

Comment: BTW, do you really need `/etc/profile` or the `.bashrc` and similar scripts run by an interactive shell, as started by `sudo -s`? You'll have a more reliable script (less prone to breaking if details of the user's dotfiles change) if you can do without them.

Answer (score 0):

SSH can run your script remotely; you can put the multiple script statements in one .sh file where your user account has permission to access and execute, and SSH should be able to run it.

Learn scripting: http://freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch08.html

Comment: The [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a long list of suggested references. We don't need to put more of them into every answer anywhere in the topic (if a question *did* ask for additional references, it would be off-topic; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (Also, `sudo -s` *won't* do what the OP wants it to when run in a script this way).

Answer (score 0):

Translating these commands into a script might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /srv/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin || exit
sudo bash -lic '. /etc/profile; exec ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown'
```

Note that we're not using `sudo -s` (which is for interactive use, and starts a *new and separate* shell), because if we did, no future lines in the script would run until that new, separate shell exited. Instead, we're using `sudo` to call `bash` with `-l` (specifying a login shell) and `-i` (specifying an interactive shell). This is *lying*, and you generally shouldn't do it in scripts -- the only reason this would help something is if you had something in root's dotfiles that your script needs to have executed, and the better answer is to explicitly put whatever logic/settings are needed directly in the script.